# SQL Server 2005 - Check for Null DateTime Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to count the number of records that have a null DateTime value. However, for some reason, my attempts have failed. I have tried the following two queries without any luck:

```
SELECT COUNT(BirthDate) 
  FROM Person p
 WHERE p.BirthDate IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(BirthDate)
  FROM Person p
 WHERE p.BirthDate = NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? I can see records with a BirthDate of NULL when I query all of the records.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person
WHERE BirthDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 17):

All answers are correct, but I'll explain why...

[COUNT(column) ignores NULLs, COUNT(*) includes NULLs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

So this works...

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Person
WHERE BirthDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) 
FROM     Person p
WHERE     p.BirthDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are trying to do a COUNT on NULL.  I think that if you check the messages tab, you may have a message there saying `NULL values eliminated from aggregate`

What you have to change is the field that you are counting

`Select Count (1) FROM Person WHERE BirthDate IS NULL`

`Select Count (*) FROM Person WHERE BirthDate IS NULL`

`Select Count (1/0) FROM Person WHERE BirthDate IS NULL`

`Select Count ('duh') FROM Person WHERE BirthDate IS NULL /* some non null string*/`

Comment: Good point with 1/0. Does it work though? ;-) In EXISTS, yes, but I've not tried it like this (and can't just now)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "IS NULL" not "= NULL"

```
SELECT
  COUNT('')
FROM
  Person p
WHERE
  BirthDate IS NULL
```

Comment: Using the empty string is less load on the DB because it doesn't retrieve any data, just an empty string.

Comment: But my understanding is that COUNT(*) doesn't load anything either. It just does a base count. At least in modern SQL Server instances.

Comment: @MattB: empty string, literal 1 or * all do the same thing. However, the reason you give is not valid.